# How do I create a Human readable sitemap in Craft CMS

Tags: plugin-sitemap

I'm just getting started with Craft (and digging it).

I've seen lots of xml sitemap plugins available already.  How do I create a human readable sitemap that will be browsable from the front end and that I can link to in the footer.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You could do this manually within a [template](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview).

This code should get you started – it will output all of the sections and their entries:

```
{# Loop through all the sections #}
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
  {# We only care about sections that have URLs #}
  {% if section.hasUrls %}
    <h2>{{ section.name }}</h2>
    <ul>
      {# Loop through each of its entries #}
      {% for entry in craft.entries.sectionId(section.id).limit(null) %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this won’t include any links to pages that only exist as a template. For example if you have a `contact.twig` template, and you don’t have a Single section in the Control Panel for it, then that will need to manually be added at the beginning or end of this list.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This combined with: http://withchief.com/blog/craft-cms-the-very-basics-of-templating really got me set up to output a useful Sitemap.  I really appreciate your help!!!